# Kendo UI Angular Upload File to Backend as Node.JS

Tags: node.js, angular, kendo-ui-angular2, multer-gridfs-storage

I am using Kendo Upload Control to upload files to Node.js backend which used GridFS multer.

**Angular**

```
<kendo-upload 
  [saveField]="file"
  [withCredentials]="false"
  [saveUrl]="uploadUrl"
  (autoUpload)="false"
  [multiple]="false"
  (select)="selectProfilePic($event)"></kendo-upload>
```

But the node.js API doesn't pick up the request. I am using `[saveField]="file"` to pass the uploaded file and the node.js below.

```
var storage = new GridFsStorage({
    //url: mongoose.connection.client.s.url,
    //options: options,
    db: mongoose.connection,
    file: (req, file) => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        myCrypto.randomBytes(16, (err, buf) => {
          if (err) {
            return reject(err);
          }
          const filename = buf.toString('hex') + path.extname(file.originalname);
          const fileInfo = {
            filename: filename,
            bucketName: 'uploads'
          };
          resolve(fileInfo);
        });
      });
    }
  });



const upload = multer({ storage });
router.post('/upload', upload.single('file'), fileUpload);

module.exports = router;

function fileUpload(req, res) {

 console.log("fileUpload")
  try {
    res.send({ file: req.file })
  }
  catch(err){

    console.log(err);
    res.send(err)
  }
}
```

**Logs**

> 2019-07-21T19:34:33.679205+00:00 app[web.1]: File Controller
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.680436+00:00 app[web.1]: {}
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983631+00:00 app[web.1]: MulterError: Unexpected
>   field 2019-07-21T19:34:33.983647+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   wrappedFileFilter (/app/node_modules/multer/index.js:40:19)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983649+00:00 app[web.1]: at Busboy.
>   (/app/node_modules/multer/lib/make-middleware.js:114:7)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983650+00:00 app[web.1]: at Busboy.emit
>   (events.js:198:13) 2019-07-21T19:34:33.983670+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   Busboy.emit (/app/node_modules/busboy/lib/main.js:38:33)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983671+00:00 app[web.1]: at PartStream.
>   (/app/node_modules/busboy/lib/types/multipart.js:213:13)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983673+00:00 app[web.1]: at PartStream.emit
>   (events.js:198:13) 2019-07-21T19:34:33.983674+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   HeaderParser. (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:51:16)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983675+00:00 app[web.1]: at HeaderParser.emit
>   (events.js:198:13) 2019-07-21T19:34:33.983677+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   HeaderParser._finish
>   (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:68:8)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983678+00:00 app[web.1]: at SBMH.
>   (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:40:12)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983679+00:00 app[web.1]: at SBMH.emit
>   (events.js:198:13) 2019-07-21T19:34:33.983680+00:00 app[web.1]: at
>   SBMH._sbmh_feed (/app/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:159:14)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983682+00:00 app[web.1]: at SBMH.push
>   (/app/node_modules/streamsearch/lib/sbmh.js:56:14)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983683+00:00 app[web.1]: at HeaderParser.push
>   (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/HeaderParser.js:46:19)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983685+00:00 app[web.1]: at Dicer._oninfo
>   (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:197:25)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.983686+00:00 app[web.1]: at SBMH.
>   (/app/node_modules/dicer/lib/Dicer.js:127:10)
>   2019-07-21T19:34:33.989908+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST
>   path="/v1/file/upload" host=herokuapp.com
>   request_id=aa1010df-d244-46bc-9b36-f8e437d5ad2a fwd="80.233.46.84"
>   dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=312ms status=500 bytes=286
>   protocol=https

Comment: Can you show some request logs? Like what is the response status/error message?

Comment: 500 Internal Server Error and I am not getting any detailed error message.

Comment: @GProst, If you see the updated code, I've changed `fileUpload` method a bit and I noticed that the fileUpload is not been hit.

Comment: Do you have error details in Node logs? Perhaps you can create a global error handler in your Express app to catch and log the error.

Also, check (with console logs) if you get inside the function where you generate file name (in Promise).

Comment: 2019-07-21T19:28:12.381336+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=POST path="/v1/file/upload" host=herokuapp.com request_id=b9b88a79-595e-457d-a63b-851603d52497 fwd="80.233.46.84" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=205ms status=500 bytes=286 protocol=https

Comment: I've already checked the logs and it just says 500 error and is there anything else to configure for detatiled error message

Comment: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html Check 'The default error handler' section. Add some logger there

Comment: @GProst, Perfect! and its `MulterError: Unexpected
> field` and updated the logs as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Is there any chance you had to set the field name to some `file` variable? So, I believe you expected `[saveField]="file"` to set field name to `'file'` string but instead it searches for some `this.file`variable which is `undefined` so you got field name set to the default `'files'` value?

Comment: Great! That's the reason.. `[saveField]="'file'"` worked

Answer (score 0):

Followed @GProst suggestions and analysed a bit and the below fix worked and I don't know the solution yet.

As per the [Kendo UI angular documentation](https://www.telerik.com/kendo-angular-ui/components/upload/api/UploadComponent/#toc-savefield),

> Sets the `FormData` key which contains the files submitted to `saveUrl`.
>   The default value is `files`.

So, I just changed the parameter name from `file` to `files` and it worked.

```
const upload = multer({ storage });
router.post('/upload', upload.single('files'), fileUpload);
```

Comment: That's strange, `saveField` should have worked. I haven't used Kendo UI but didn't find any open issues in their GitHub repo about any problems with setting field name

Comment: Yes, but it didn't work and maybe I can report this to Kendo